# Create a nonlinear mapping that simulates ripples in an image

Tags: nonlinear, generative-art

Assume an image is viewed through a horizontal layer of water, and we want to use nonlinear mapping to simulate the ripples in such an image.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because you have not shown what you have tried, nor demonstrated how the question is related to the Mathematica software

Answer (score 7):

Here's one possibility:

```
ImageTransformation[
 ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}],
 # + 0.05 {0, 1} Sin@Norm[60 (# - {0.5, 0.5})] &
]
```

[image]

Comment: Going for a Reversal badge? :)